# elasticsearch & nginx: basic authorithation different users right for one site

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, basic-authentication

Issue:
I need to configure Elasticsearch/Kibana basic authorization with basic license. But I need to do this:

For user `kibana` I want to grant access to all http methods (`GET, POST, DELETE`), however for user `logger` (which will post log/metric events) I want to grant only `POST` method.

I know, it is possible to configure it like that:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  logger.domain.com;

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        auth_basic      "secured site tools";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/example/.htpasswd_logger;

        add_header Allow "POST" always;
        if ( $request_method !~ ^(POST)$ ) {
            return 405;
        }
   }
}

server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  kibana.domain.com;

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        auth_basic      "secured site tools";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/example/.htpasswd_kibana;
   }
}
```

**BUT** I want to have a single entry point `elastic.domain.com` with differently configured method rules for different users. Is it possible?

Or can anyone suggest different **FREE** tool with X-Pack security functionality?